# Engine oil found in the radiator - how did it get there?

Tags: engine

What could be the possible cause of oil leaking into the radiator when the engine is running?

I have changed the O-rings on the oil cooler and pressure tested the cooler.

Comment: How's the head gasket?

Answer (score 9):

The oil cooler is one possible place where oil and coolant could mix, but there are other culprits:

- a ***compromised head gasket*** can allow oil to mix into the cylinder head's cooling jacket
- a ***warped cylinder head*** can do the same.